# Raspberry Zero Pi W - MongoDB + Node.js backend

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, node.js, mongodb

I am planning to programm some home dashboard and I want to use Raspberry Zero Pi W as my server. I wanted to ask you, if it´s a good idea to run on Zero node.js backend and mongodb database from performance perspective. I don´t need extra power, it will run only on local network and serve only one client.

Thanks for your opinios.

Comment: Do you realise you're limited to mongodb v2.x (current version is 4.2.3) on pi since it's only a 32bit processor?

Comment: Oh, I don´t... So I should probably use Rpi4B for this project, right?

Comment: if you're using Raspbian then it won't make a difference, since userland in Raspbian is always 32bit - other distros for raspberry pi that are true 64 bit (arm64) do exist, Ubuntu Server is one https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi - that can run on a pi2 (I think the second release of the pi2 only) pi3 or pi4 - unless you have a 2 or 3 lying around, buy a pi4

Comment: There is a 64-bit version of Gentoo Linux for RPi3B, 3B+, 3A+ and 4B.